# Pass custom parameter to ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on this springboot application where I need to do some validations on values passed from http call and I'm using class level validation [as explained here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

I'm using somethink like this:

```
@ValidRequest
public class EventRequest {
    String date;
}

Response create(@Valid EventRequest request) {
     ..
}
Response update(Long entityId, @Valid EventRequest request) {
     ...
}

public class ValidRequestValidator 
  implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRequest, EventRequest> {
```

In the class ValidRequestValidator, where I implement the ConstraintValidator interface, I need to check if there is another Event entity in the database that meet some conditions on field date. When I want to create a new entity is simple, I perform a query, but when I need to update I need to exclude the entity I'm currently trying to update.

Is there a way to pass entityId parameter to @ValidRequest custom validator?
I know a way is to add the field entityId to the class EventRequest, but I would like to maintain this separation because entityId is coming from a query parameter.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional to the field-specific(`Single Parameter Constraint`) you can implement constraint for the whole method(`Cross-Parameter Constraint`). This will provide ability to pass all parameters of certain method to validator.

**Annotation definition:**

Annotation used two validators and can be applied to the Method or Type.

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = {ValidRequestMethodValidator.class, ValidRequestTypeValidator.class})
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidRequest {
    String message() default "Request is invalid!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    ConstraintTarget validationAppliesTo() default ConstraintTarget.IMPLICIT;
}
```

**Constraint Validator which will handle single parameter:**

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class ValidRequestTypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRequest, EventRequest> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(EventRequest request, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
       // logic here
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Constraint Validator which will handle all parameters of specific method:**

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.constraintvalidation.SupportedValidationTarget;
import javax.validation.constraintvalidation.ValidationTarget;

@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class ValidRequestMethodValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRequest, Object[]> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] objects, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        Long entityId = null;
        EventRequest eventRequest = null;

        if (objects[0] instanceof Long) {
            entityId = (Long) objects[0];
        }
        if (objects[0] instanceof EventRequest) {
            eventRequest = (EventRequest) objects[0];
        }
        if (objects[1] instanceof EventRequest) {
            eventRequest = (EventRequest) objects[1];
        }
        //logic here
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Please note,** we have to annotate the beans, which shall be validated, with `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` annotation to get method validators to work automatically.

**Example of usage:**

1. Mixed usage, `@ValidRequest` annotation defined on method and single parameter level.

```java
@ValidRequest
public class EventRequest {
    public String value;
}

@RestController
@Validated
public class Controller {

    Response create(@Valid EventRequest request) {
     return new Response();
    }

    @ValidRequest(validationAppliesTo = ConstraintTarget.PARAMETERS)
    Response update(Long entityId, EventRequest request) {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

For `create` method `ValidRequestTypeValidator` will be executed.

For `update` method `ValidRequestMethodValidator`  will be executed.

2. Define annotation only for methods

```java
@RestController
@Validated
public class Controller {

    @ValidRequest(validationAppliesTo = ConstraintTarget.PARAMETERS)
    Response create(EventRequest request) {
     return new Response();
    }

    @ValidRequest(validationAppliesTo = ConstraintTarget.PARAMETERS)
    Response update(Long entityId, EventRequest request) {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

For `create` method `ValidRequestMethodValidator`  will be executed with one element objects array

For `update` method `ValidRequestMethodValidator`  will be executed with two elements objects array

3. Define annotation for a single parameter and method at the same time

```java
@ValidRequest
public class EventRequest {
    public String value;
}

@RestController
@Validated
public class Controller {

    @ValidRequest(validationAppliesTo = ConstraintTarget.PARAMETERS)
    Response update(Long entityId, @Valid EventRequest request) {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

First will be executed single parameter validator `ValidRequestTypeValidator`.

If it will passed validation then second method validator `ValidRequestMethodValidator` will be executed.

Probably only one method-level validation will be sufficient to handle your issue. I described all variants, just for information maybe will be useful.

Comment: I never heard of this three options and It's very interesting to know all three scenarios.
As you pointed out for my use case I think the best is option 2.